# Laravel: How to create a custom foreach Blade directive

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to create a custom foreach Blade directive. I know I could use the one provided out of the box but I just thought I'd make my own custom one.

My purpose is to create this directive:

> @foremails    {{ $email->email }} @endforemails

```
Blade::directive('foremails', function () {
    return "<?php foreach($data->contract->emails as $email): ?>";
});

Blade::directive('endforemails', function () {
    return "<?php endforeach; ?>";
});
```

Also I don't want to have to pass an argument like so @foremails('$data') but only have **@foremails** because I think that looks pretty clean.

My code is giving me an error: Undefined variable: data

If I try to pass a parameter function($data) it gives me an error: Trying to get property 'contract' of non-object

And if I try function ($data->contract->emails) then I get: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ')'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could help you:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/custom-blade-directive

Seems like you have to excape the variable

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing, I didn't know I had to escape it. Thank you!